# Hard drive enclosure fell over (90 degrees) while hdd was running, but not copying/writing - how can I tell if the needle scratched the disk?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

**PURPOSE**: determine what, if any, way there is to check if the hdd needle scratched the hdd causing great damage.

The external hdd was in an enclosure and tipped over, fell 90 degrees, hitting the table with a lot of force b/c the hdd is very heavy. The hdd was running/on, and I had a file open from the hdd, but it was not writing or copying any files.

There are thousands and thousands of files on the hdd - too many too open and see if they were damaged.

Any way to check the disk? Will checking the health of the hard drive with fdisk do any good?

Comment: What filesystem? You could run `e2fsck` if it's ext2/3/4.

Comment: Many hard drives (especially those meant for laptops) autopark the head when they detect a drop, so you could be lucky. What is the exact disk model? Tipping over and falling on its side is also not that much of a shock. Otherwise, no way to tell without actually accessing the files (try to read a dozen  or so, may be do a MD5 hash and compare with a backup...).

Comment: @Attie Yes, ext4. Thanks.

Comment: @xenoid Yes, I will open some, but that won't fully tell me. At the same time, if many of them had problems, it would tell me. Model #: HUS726T4TALA6L4. Thanks.

Comment: Not a laptop drive (really meant for datacenters), but specs boast a protection against vibrations.

Comment: @Attie  Now that I think about it, the hdd was originally setup as ext4, but more than half of the files on the hdd are ntfs as they were copied from another hdd that had ntfs filesystem. Should I still run it as e2fsck?

Comment: "_Files_" aren't either ext4 or NTFS - the "_filesystem_" is... If you made an ext4 filesystem on the partition, whether you created the files directly or copied files from another filesystem is irrelevant.

Comment: Note also that ext4 is unable to verify whether the contents of the files are correct, so bitrot, read errors, and potentially a damaged platter surface are impossible to detect just by "_reading the files_"... you'll need to compare against a backup / checksum... or if the relevant application has integrity checks use them (e.g: `gzip`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a tool to perform a full surface scan of the disk drive. This is also sometimes called a “long DST” test or just a “long” test in some manufacturer’s tools. There are multiple ways to do this.

1. [`chkdsk <Drive:> /r`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk)
2. [HDDScan](https://hddscan.com/) read test
3. The drive manufacturer’s test tool.

Other tools are available as well. The above are all free ways to do it.

Of course, I don’t need to tell you to backup all your data first. That should already be done.

Comment: question has a Linux tag

Comment: at Appleoddity: Thanks. The 2 two tools seem to be for windows though. The filesystem is ext4 and I am using a linux OS to test it, though I could use windows OS if necessary.

Comment: *I don’t need to tell you to backup all your data first.* **No!!!!** Or at least not on your usual backup media, otherwise you run the risk to overwrite a good backup with a corrupt file.

Comment: For Linux, see the `smartmontools` package. It lets you look at your SMART data and run a few tests. Caution: SMART data may look terrible, but manufacturers often encode several bytes ad a long int, so you have to see the actual doc of you drive to interpret some of the numbers.

Comment: @xenoid Thanks for your comments. "the actual doc of you drive " What doc is this and where can I find it? Not familiar with 'smartmontools'. Should my hdd be mounted when using it? Thx.

Comment: 1) on the manufacturer's site, in some "support" section 2) connected, yes, mounted as a filesystem, no. Just getting the error counts can be done whether the filesystems are mounted or not. WD also seems to have a "Lifeguard" app to inspect disks.